# My mesh looks fine with Dynamic Topology enabled, but has weird artifacts when disabled

Tags: topology, sculpting, dynamic-topology

The mesh looks like this with dynamic topology enabled.
[image: mesh with dynamic topology enabled]

When I disable dynamic topology and when I'm outside of sculpt mode it looks like this. 
[image: mesh with dynamic topology disabled]

I made a mesh using multiple meshes and combining them with the re-mesh tool. Perhaps that's the cause of the problem? I'm not really an artist, so I may be making a rookie mistake.

Comment: I noticed you have a normal map there. Is that affecting the bump of the object? Does this happen on other objects? Also, the matcap may be making this look more pronounced, although I don't think the matcap is the cause. You have Dyntopo's Smooth Shading enabled while sculpting, and I think that's why you see the difference when you switch modes or disable Dyntopo, but what is causing the difference I am not sure. I suspect the bump of the material, but without the .blend I can only guess.